# SFTP pwd command option to show full path of the current remote working directory

Tags: windows-10, sftp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have specified a home directory for an sftp by setting /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to something like this.

```
Match User sftp-hello_world
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp-user/sftp-hello_world
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 002
```

when I cannot to the sftp using the said user, it shows the relative path and not the full remote working directory.

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
```

I am not sure what if it is a sftp client problem or a remote server setting problem. What do you think?

I was expecting something like this.

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/sftp-user/sftp-hello_world/
```

My environment is a Windows 10 with a subsystem linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. The server side is an Amazon Linux AMI if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct behavior. That's what *chroot* is.

It actually seems that, what you want, is to set the `/home/sftp-user/sftp-hello_world` as the *home directory* of the `sftp-hello_world` user.